# OpenSSL генерация сертификата для всех доменов

Tags: ssl, openssl

Добрый день. Есть задача сделать сертификат ssl для всех доменов, точно знаю что можно. Пробовал вот что-то такое http://apetec.com/support/generatesan-csr.htm но в конечном итоге ничего не вышло. Если кто-то обладает информацией по этому поводу - прошу помочь и расписать как это реализовать.

Comment: т.е вам самописные сертификаты нужны ?

Comment: да, для моей задачи

Comment: какая панель хостинга ? какой хостинг ?

Comment: Сервер мой. Да и какое это значение имеет. Все равно генерируем через openssl

Comment: смысл вопроса был в том, что если используйте cPanel или ISP manager или что то в этом роде, на них можно быстро сгенерировать SSL сертификат

Comment: ну просто мне надо с особыми надстройками, что бы этот сертификат подходил ко всем доменам....по идеи как то можно по зонам сделать типа *.com *.net и тд. Только как

Comment: Вам сертификат для всех доменов в мире нужен?

Comment: [How to add multiple DNS names to a certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23587047/6219657)

Comment: @zed списобо огромное! Всегда меня спасаешь :)